# Change keys value in foreach PHP

Tags: php

It is possible to change "keys" values in foreach PHP? For example I have database like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ep9sl.png

And I want to get this data, and display it in:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
... 
}
```

How can I change the "keys" if i don't want do display, for example "u_group" but "Group"?

PS. Sorry for my bad english ^ ^"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create some language array, where keys are `$key` and value is proper text.

E.g:

```
$langs = ['u_group' => 'Group', 'u_other' => 'Other'];
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    echo 'User ' . $langs[$key] . ': ' . $value;
}
```